Unable to pass props to page.tsx from layout.tsx
I'm building a Next.js application with the app router, where the `layout.tsx` file manages a button state that I want to use for rendering different content in `page.tsx`. I understand that `layout.tsx` serves as a wrapper for the content in `page.tsx`, and I need to pass the state from the layout to the page so it can determine which component to render based on the state's value. However, I'm unsure how to implement this.
Since, I am exporting the MetaData from layout.tsx file, I can't make it the client-side rendering component. So, I have explicitly made a RootLayoutClient.tsx component which receives the children from parent layout.tsx.
This is the project structure currently.

// layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "./globals.css";
import RootLayoutClient from "./RootLayoutClient";
import { Open_Sans } from 'next/font/google';

const openSans = Open_Sans({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "xxxx",
  description: "yyyy",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={openSans.className}>
        <RootLayoutClient>{children}</RootLayoutClient>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

// RootLayoutClient.tsx
'use client';

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function RootLayoutClient({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState('today');
    console.log(children);
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Navbar selectedButton={selectedButton} setSelectedButton={setSelectedButton} />
    </div>
  );
}

import Inbox from "./components/content/Inbox";
import Today from "./components/content/Today";
import Upcoming from "./components/content/Upcoming";
import FiltersAndLabels from "./components/content/FiltersAndLabels";

export default function Home({selectedButton}: {selectedButton: string}) {
  console.log(selectedButton);
  const renderContent = () => {
    switch (selectedButton) {
      case 'inbox':
        return <Inbox/>
      case 'today':
        return <Today/>
      case 'upcoming':
        return <Upcoming/>
      case 'filtersAndLabels':
        return <FiltersAndLabels/>
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
  return (
    <main>
          {renderContent()}
    </main>
  );
}

Can someone help me figure out the way around to deal with this?

can you provide a GitHub repo

Layout, more generally "wrapper", components don't generally explicitly pass props to the children components they are wrapping. They don't know what they will be wrapping to know what specifically to pass.
You could use the Children helper and cloneElement to inject additional props:
import { cloneElement, Children, useState } from "react";

export default function RootLayoutClient({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState('today');

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Navbar
        selectedButton={selectedButton}
        setSelectedButton={setSelectedButton}
      />
      {Children.map(children, child => {
        return cloneElement(child, { selectedButton, setSelectedButton });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

The wrapped children components will now have access to the injected selectedButton and setSelectedButton prop values. This generally works quite well in non-Typescript projects, but with TS these additional props would need to be known about in any and all components that are wrapped so they are typed correctly in those component's props interface.
Alternative
The alternative, and likely preferable, solution is to provide the "props" values down the ReactTree via a React context provider.
Example:
const SelectButtonContext = createContext<{
  selectedButton: string;
  setSelectedButton: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
}>({
  selectedButton: "";
  setSelectedButton: (value: string) => {};
});

const useSelectButtonContext = React.useContext(SelectButtonContext);

export default function RootLayoutClient({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState('today');

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Navbar
        selectedButton={selectedButton}
        setSelectedButton={setSelectedButton}
      />
      <SelectButtonContext.Provider
        value={{ selectedButton, setSelectedButton }}
      >
        {children}
      </SelectButtonContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Home() {
  const { selectedButton } = useSelectButtonContext();

  const renderContent = () => {
    switch (selectedButton) {
      case 'inbox':
        return <Inbox />;

      case 'today':
        return <Today />;

      case 'upcoming':
        return <Upcoming />;

      case 'filtersAndLabels':
        return <FiltersAndLabels />;

      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {renderContent()}
    </main>
  );
}

